# salesforce reports hiding header

Tags: reporting, custom-report-type

Can you hide the title report and buttons of a report and just show the report body?

Example.
only show the body and not show the Report Options, Buttons and Report Title?

Exporting wont work because its going to be used on a screen.  So imagine using a TV and only showing the body data.  Use a plugin that will refresh every hour and then you have a report system thats being updated every hour.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: use case please, whats the trouble exporting the report, you would only see the body and no buttons

Comment: Sorry Rao,  It's actually used for a TV.  so when I walk in the hallway and I want to see records being updated every hour I just see the body data and not the hyperlinks, buttons, etc.

Comment: why not a VF page?

Comment: @crop1645 can you link me or navigate?

Comment: a VisualForce (VF) page can look like any HTML page you want. It can be attached to a controller that fetches data that is then formatted according to the VF page definition. VF action poller can then be used to auto-refresh. Scope of question is rather broad but these should give you some pointers into the doc